# Flutter: Is it safe if I remove the code of flutter_native_splash & flutter_launcher_icons after run this code?

Tags: flutter

I have tried to remove these codes.

```
flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "1024.png"
  adaptive_icon_foreground: "512.png"

flutter_native_splash:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image: "A.png"
```

The app still works successfully.
So, is it safe to remove these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are tools to generate app icon and splash screen, so yes it is safe after generate those to remove them, but when yo decide to change app icon or splash screen you need to add them again.

Comment: your welcome. If it was useful, please approve it so other people could find it easier.